# How to automatically put URLs in footnotes?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, endnotes, handout

Suppose I have a document with a few hyperref links within paragraphs of text.

`...research on related topics. \href{https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2020/03/09/thomas-piketty-goes-global}{\emph{The New Yorker} discusses Piketty's views} on ...`

Someone who prints this out won't know the URL; only someone who views it electronically can access the URL.

Is there a package or option to automatically create footnotes or citations with the URLs of all external hyperlinks in the document?

Here is a half-way solution. It ***only*** needs a command like `\customcite{http://myurl.com/abc}{2022-11-21}` that inserts an entry into the bib and then calls `\cite{key}` with the corresponding key. (This is above my pay-grade to create.) I am hoping that some package would automate this.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Solution}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\dots research on related topics. \emph{The New Yorker} \cite{NewYorkerOnPiketty} discusses Piketty's views on \dots 

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{NewYorkerOnPiketty}
  \url{https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2020/03/09/thomas-piketty-goes-global}. Accessed: 2022-11-21.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled solution]

Comment: Suggestion: a) define a \newcommand, which b) puts a foot- or endnote AND c) uses \url from package hyperref. // Please don't forget to put some compileable code next time.

Comment: Thanks--yeah, that's probably the way to go.

Comment: The way you show it in the example: why won‘t citations work?

Comment: @MS-SPO Thanks for your response. Yeah, I was hoping that there already exists a package that makes that custom command work nicely. I improved my question above.